# How to extract information from a txt document

Tags: python, list

So i have the raw txt  right here :

```
 IR DATA - TIME IN NAV = 40 MINUTES 

    NAME  LABEL    DATA                     DECODED MESSAGE
    ----- -----    ----------               ----------------------------------
    LATIT (310)    X'E4554813'              48.747711
    LONGI (311)    X'E036ED93'              2.413731
    GNDSP (312)    X'E0008153'              0.500000
    TRHDG (314)    X'7400B933'              -134.972534
    PITCH (324)    X'E000352B'              0.005493
    ROLL  (325)    X'7FFE55AB'              -0.076904
    N-VEL (366)    X'E000216F'              0.125000
    E-VEL (367)    X'60007DEF'              0.375000
    FAULT (270)    X'0008111D'
                                            IN NAV MODE            
                                            DC FAIL-ON DC {FAIL WHILE ON DC}
    MAINT (350)    X'00000D17'


 IR DATA - TIME IN NAV = 45 MINUTES 

    NAME  LABEL    DATA                     DECODED MESSAGE
    ----- -----    ----------               ----------------------------------
    LATIT (310)    X'64554613'              48.747368
    LONGI (311)    X'E036F093'              2.414246
    GNDSP (312)    X'6000AD53'              0.625000
    TRHDG (314)    X'7400B933'              -134.972534
    PITCH (324)    X'E000352B'              0.005493
    ROLL  (325)    X'7FFE55AB'              -0.076904
    N-VEL (366)    X'FFFF516F'              -0.750000
    E-VEL (367)    X'E00001EF'              0.000000
    FAULT (270)    X'0008111D'
                                            IN NAV MODE            
                                            DC FAIL-ON DC {FAIL WHILE ON DC}
    MAINT (350)    X'00000D17'
```

What i want to extract on two different list is that :
[image: THE INFORMATION]

After extracting this information (there are about 10) I will make a graph to make the result more visual like that :
[image]

I would like to know how I can extract this data in particular.

Comment: what have you tried so far

Comment: I was able to get other datas and display them, but it was simple because it was like a tab, but now as a raw text i dont know how  i can do.

Comment: Iterate through each line, if the line starts with IR DATA get the time, then if it starts with N-VEL or E-VEL get the data using `split` and put both of them in seperate lists or a dictionary

Comment: @Ani thanks for your answer, but how can I do the "check" and know when it starts with N-VEL and E-VEL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```
import re

with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    text = f_in.read()

list1 = list(
    map(float, re.findall(r"N-VEL.*?([\d\.-]+)\s*$", text, flags=re.M))
)
list2 = list(
    map(float, re.findall(r"E-VEL.*?([\d\.-]+)\s*$", text, flags=re.M))
)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

Prints:

```
[0.125, -0.75]
[0.375, 0.0]
```

Comment: if it's a large file just be aware this iterates over the file twice

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate over the file once and check the strings based on your criteria.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("foo.txt", "r") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        tmp = line.strip().split()
        try:
            val = tmp[0]
        except IndexError:
            continue
        if val in ("N-VEL", "E-VEL"):
            d[val].append(float(tmp[-1]))
        else:
            continue

print(d)
>> defaultdict(list, {'N-VEL': [0.125, -0.75], 'E-VEL': [0.375, 0.0]})
```